# PHP reads wrong data from Ajax request.. Not cache problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this request:

```
var pref_way = $('.contact_types:checked').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "/ajax/send_group_order.php?rnd="+ Math.random(),
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        "pref_way": pref_way,
        "bsk_pid": bsk_pid,
        "bsk_aid": bsk_aid,
        "customer_names": customer_names,
        "customer_email": customer_email,
        "customer_phone": customer_phone
    }, 
    success: function(data){
        alert(pref_way);
    }
});
```

Please, Have a look what the server reads:
var_dump($_REQUEST); returns:

```
array(7) { 
    ["rnd"]=> string(19) "0.39372841006323167" 
    ["pref_way"]=> string(4) "both" 
    ["bsk_pid"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(3) "445" 
        [1]=> string(3) "441" 
        [2]=> string(3) "435" 
    } 
    ["bsk_aid"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(2) "94" 
    } 
    ["customer_names"]=> string(6) "dfsdfs" 
    ["customer_email"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["customer_phone"]=> string(14) "00359894624093" 
}
```

Do you notice that JS sends pref_way = "phone", but PHP reads pref_way as "both"

if I check $_POST['pref_way'] it gives me "phone" but $_REQUEST['pref_way'] returns "both" .. First time I see such thing..

[image]

What could cause this?
Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Please show how you set pref_way, else it simply looks like you got confused in what you sent up, look for `both` in codebase and remove it.. does that fix the issue?

Comment: are you by any chance dumping $_REQUEST? as your array seems to also be including `rnd` which was a GET param not in the post.. if so check for a cookie called pref_way

Comment: I showed how pref_way is getted.. That's not the problem because please look at the screenshot that shows what is sent.. "phone" in the example..

Comment: #Lawrence Cherone - yes this is $_REQUEST dump which I showed from the php side

Comment: if I check $_POST['pref_way'] it gives me "phone" but if I check $_REQUEST['pref_way'] returns "both" .. First time I see such thing..

Comment: can you show server side code ??

Comment: Guys, I discovered the problem to be that I have set also a $_COOKIE['pref_way'] - with the same name and its treated also as $_REQUEST..

Thank you for your time and sorry for wasting your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$REQUEST contains: $COOKIE, $GET, and $POST variables

if you use **$_REQUEST** you have no guarantee that the data came from the post data, which leads to ***security holes in your script***

also, if the is a `$GET['var'] = 'foo';` and `$POST['var'] = 'something else';` the `$_REQUEST['var']` would be the last one set (i think, not sure)

check if you have used 'pref_way' before in GET or COOKIE variable